# (CSS & HTML) CSS doesn't load

Tags: html, css

I'm having some weird trouble with my css, It doesn't load!?
So I'm using google chrome to preview it on and it always had worked fine,
until I started to ad meta tags. This is the code that I'm using;

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

mainContainer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sander™ - Code & Design</title>
    <link href="stylehome.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="description" content="Welcome to my website - Sander™ - Code & Design">
    <meta name="author" content="Sander™ - Code & Design">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Minecraft Server, RPG, Nederlands, 24/7, Beste Minecraft Server, NL server">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="javaScript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mainContainer">
    
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And I don't know why it's not previewing, I can't find any spell mistakes,
and overall I always had done it this way (only not the meta tags) and I always worked fine. So if somebody can spot something wrong please tell me.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: #mainContainer { ... } instead of mainContainer {...}

Answer (score 3):

`mainContainer` is a [type selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#type-selectors) that matches all `<mainContainer>` elements, which you don't have any of and aren't allowed in HTML anyway.

You need an [ID selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#id-selectors), which starts with a `#` character.

Comment: Okey I'm a bit schocked that I missed that, But thank u somuch for the fast  response